# Highlighting the SQL schema name

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

In VS Code, when selecting the SQL language, the keywords are highlighted. I need the schemas, tables, or aliases that stand in front of the dot to be highlighted in a different color (below shows what should be highlighted).

The code should look something like this:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfRyr.png)

Here's the code used in the above screenshot for your repro purposes:

```sql
SELECT TABLE.COL1, T2.COL2
FROM SCHEMA1.TABLE1
INNER JOIN SCHEMA1.TABLE2 AS T2 ON TABLE1.COL1 = T2.COL2
```

I don't understand how the SQL code highlighting settings work in VS Code and I can't find instructions on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `Developer: Inspect Editor Token and Scopes` command in the command palette and put the caret in the contexts you want to customize colours for, you'll see that they have the `constant.other.database-name.sql` TextMate scope (which is odd, since not all of them are database names- some are table names (I suspect [the builtin TextMate grammar for SQL in VS Code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/sql/syntaxes/sql.tmLanguage.json) is not either very good, or hitting technical limitations of TextMate grammars)), so you can use the following config:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[<Theme Name>]": { // TODO insert your theme's name, or remove this wrapper block to apply to all themes
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": "constant.other.database-name.sql",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#FF0000", // TODO
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
```